# Add columns if layer intersects more than one other layer in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, attribute-joins

I have been spatially joining land use zones to parcels successfully with the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE new_parcel AS
SELECT DISTINCT ON(t.geom) t.*, m.basezone, m.overlay
FROM parcel AS t
LEFT JOIN zoning AS m
  ON st_intersects(t.geom, m.geom)
  AND st_area(st_intersection(t.geom, m.geom)) / st_area(t.geom) > 0.5
```

Currently, more than 50% of the parcel's area must be within a single zone for a join to occur.

However, it turns out that some of the parcels overlap 3 or more zones and are not getting joined to the `zoning` table because less than 50% of their area overlaps.  For example, the parcels of dark purple color overlap more than two zones:

[image]

How would one modify the query to add extra columns in the resulting table which would include data from all zones overlapped?

The existing code produces a table that has

```
basezone | overlay
```

How could one produce

```
basezone_2|overlay_2|basezone_3|overlay_3|...
```

and so on for all zones overlapped?

Comment: Got any sample data?

Comment: Remove the distinct clause and add sum(ST_Area(ST_Intersection(....  I think, so you would get the sum of all intersected areas for any given t.geom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for isn't easy because you don't know how many columns to produce until *after* the query is complete. [`crosstab` from tablefunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) will permit some of this, but because you're not providing any sample data it's damn near impossible.

As a mater of the join,

In order to first tell which zones overlap multiple zones with more than 50% of their area, you have to

1. Calculate all zones that overlap with a join of parcel/zoning,
2. Calculate the area of the overlap.

Then afterward, you can see if the combined overlap is greater tan 50%.

A join operation works row-wise. There is no concept of a join based on a function of the other table the row. Modifying your query, it would look something like this...

First, you need the

```
SELECT t.parcel
FROM (
  SELECT p.geom AS parcel,
    m.geom AS zoning,
    st_area(st_intersection(p.geom, m.geom)) AS areaintersection
  FROM parcel AS p
  JOIN zoning AS m
    ON st_intersects(p.geom, m.geom)
) AS t
GROUP BY t.parcel
HAVING sum(areaintersection) / st_area(t.geom) > 0.5;
```

Now, should be a result set of `parcel.geom`. From there, you can `INNER JOIN` back to parcel, and to zoning to get a list that you can feed to `crosstab()`.